# Getting "label redefined" error using local label inside an inline/einline block in VASM

Tags: assembly, z80

First of all, this is my very first question on assembly, and I am still at the very beginning of my (hopefully long) learning journey, so forgive me if some terms are completely wrong (I hope my question at least makes some sense).

I am using VASM assembler to build a Z80 program.

I have a subroutine that makes use of VASM's `inline`/`einline` directives to define local labels [as explained in the docs](http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vasm/release/vasm_6.html).

The part of the code which gives me the error on compilation is the following:

```
PlayerSprY:
; player Y SPRITES' VERTICAL IN SAT
; Parameters: hl = SATY address
; Affects: a, hl, b
    rept 4                     ; repeat 4 times as player is 4 tiles tall
    inline                     ; use local name space (VASM does not have local name space like WLA-DX)
    ld b,3                     ; counter 3 as player is tile wide
    PlayerSprYLoop:
        out (VDPData),a
        inc hl
        djnz PlayerSprYLoop    ; decrease B and jump back if NonZero
    add a,8                    ; add 8 (since next row is 8 pixels below.)
    einline                    ; end of local name space (http://eab.abime.net/showthread.php?t=88827)
    endr                       ; end of rept

    ret
```

And the error I get is:

```
error 75 in line 3 of "REPEAT:Hello World.asm:line 192": label <PlayerSprYLoop> redefined
    included from line 192 of "Hello World.asm"
>    PlayerSprYLoop:
```

I understand that `PlayerSprYLoop` label is redefined 4 times due to `rept 4`, but I thought that placing my definition within an `inline`/`einline` block would have prevented this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have already found out the answer.

In [the same docs I pointed out](http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vasm/release/vasm_6.html), it reads

> Local labels are preceded by ’.’ or terminated by ’$’. For the rest,
> any alphanumeric character including ’_’ is allowed. Local labels are
> valid between two global label definitions.

Therefore, this code compiles correctly (note that `PlayerSprYLoop` became `.PlayerSprYLoop`):

```
PlayerSprY:
; player Y SPRITES' VERTICAL IN SAT
; Parameters: hl = SATY address
; Affects: a, hl, b
    rept 4                     ; repeat 4 times as player is 4 tiles tall
    inline                     ; use local name space (VASM does not have local name space like WLA-DX)
    ld b,3                     ; counter 3 as player is tile wide
    .PlayerSprYLoop:
        out (VDPData),a
        inc hl
        djnz .PlayerSprYLoop    ; decrease B and jump back if NonZero
    add a,8                    ; add 8 (since next row is 8 pixels below.)
    einline                    ; end of local name space (http://eab.abime.net/showthread.php?t=88827)
    endr                       ; end of rept

    ret
```